Why can't I use POSIX threads to keep a stack frame open?
Before reading onward, please understand a few things:
I know POSIX has implemented methods of passing arguments back to the calling functions. I know what I'm trying to do here is bad, and should never be tried seriously. Please understand that I'm just trying to understand how the compiler treats memory and stack frames, so that I can avoid memory errors in the future. This is not a question of 'how', but 'why not'.
I've been taught that return values to the calling function should be by value, and not by reference like so:
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct some_struct {
    int val1;
    int val2;
} some_struct;

some_struct remote() {
    some_struct s;
    s.val1 = 1;
    s.val2 = 2;
    return s;
}

int main() {
    some_struct by_value = remote();
    printf("%d %d\n", by_value.val1, by_value.val2);    //prints '1 2'
    return 0;
}

If instead we return a reference to something that was declared in the callee function, then we have a problem:
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct some_struct {
    int val1;
    int val2;
} some_struct;

some_struct* remote() {
    some_struct s;
    s.val1 = 1;
    s.val2 = 2;
    return &s;
}

int main() {
    some_struct *by_reference = remote();
    printf("%d %d\n", by_reference -> val1, by_reference -> val2);  //prints '1 2' ...sometimes.
    return 0;
}

My understanding about why this is, is that when control is returned from a function, the compiler treats that callee function's stack frame as freed, and will overwrite it at its own pleasure. Therefore if in a caller function a value in the callee function's stack frame is referenced, there is a high chance that the compiler has already decided to overwrite that space with something else (unless it's a very small program like this one, in which case it will return the correct values if you are extraordinarily (un)lucky.)
So that got me thinking. Could I potentially use posix threads to keep the callee function's stack frame open?
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>

typedef struct some_struct {
    int val1;
    int val2;
} some_struct;

int semaphore1 = 1;
int semaphore2 = 1;

void* remote(void* arg) {
    some_struct s;
    s.val1 = 1;
    s.val2 = 2;
    arg = &s;
    
    semaphore1 = 0;
    while(semaphore2) sleep(1);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread;   
    some_struct *by_reference;

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, remote, (void*)by_reference);
    while(semaphore1) sleep(1);
    printf("%d %d\n", by_reference -> val1, by_reference -> val2);    //seg faults
    semaphore2 = 0;
    return 0;
}


The answer is no. Running this program ends in a segmentation fault.
Why is that? why doesn't the thread keep the stack frame open while the argument is being referenced? Or, is something else causing this seg fault?

You never allocated any memory for by_reference to point to. Assigning to arg doesn't assign to by_reference.

int semaphore1 = 1; and then while(semaphore1) sleep(1); in the parent thread and semphore1 = 0; in the child thread is flat-out broken.

What you need is pthread_create(&thread, NULL, remote, (void*)&by_reference); Then in the function you need to do *(some_struct**)arg = &s;

You should use real semaphores rather than int variables for synchronization.

Re "I've been taught that return values to the calling function should be by value, and not by reference like so:", That's wrong. C always passes by value and always returns by value. You can't pass by reference. You can't return by reference. You don't have a choice in this. /// Maybe you meant "a pointer" when you said "by reference"—a common mistake—but that's wrong too. You can pass pointers to a function. You can return pointers from a function. /// What you can't do is return a pointer to a local ("automatic") variable.
